Sutton-Barto confusing notation for the target and behaviour policy in the expected sarsa
Sutton-Barto, page 134, second paragraph:

In these cliff walking results Expected Sarsa was used on-policy, but in general it
might use a policy different from the target policy $\pi$ to generate behavior, in which case
it becomes an off-policy algorithm.

I am confused here. Sutton-Barto was using $\pi$ for target policy and $b$ for the behaviour policy. Why now are they saying "target policy $\pi$ to generate behavior"?

I'm not sure I understand what the doubt is, but here they are saying that you may use a behaviour policy $b$ which is different than $\pi$ (the target policy). In SARSA, you usually have $b = \pi$, but this is expected SARSA. If this answers your question, I'll convert it to a format answer

Just look at the sentence again, you've quoted it correctly and then only pulled half the noun phrase into your question . . . it's not talking about a "target policy $\pi$" - it's talking about a "policy different from the target policy $\pi$"!

In my opinion the wording is bad. It must be like this: " it might use a policy different from the policy to generate behavior, in which case it becomes an off-policy algorithm."

It's normal English phrasing. "A cat different from next door's cat just walked past the window". Your suggestion doesn't make sense, and is ambiguous where S&B is not -  it would be like "A cat different from the cat just walked past the window" . . . unless you've missed something out in your comment above?

S&B introduced  $\pi$ for target policy and $b$ for the behaviour policy when discussing off-policy. In my opinion, when there is a discussion related to target and behaviour policy (or on-policy, off-policy), they should stick to this notation.

If you want a more formal approach with strict notation and less informal English,  there is an alternative to S&B with a good reputation

I will try to find a link to it for you

Nowdays it seems there are dozens. I think the book I am recalling is this https://sites.ualberta.ca/~szepesva/papers/RLAlgsInMDPs.pdf (official free version) But there's also this one: https://faculty.utrgv.edu/weidong.kuang/book/RL.pdf that seems like a work in progress. There's also this which looks promising: https://www.mit.edu/~dimitrib/RLCOURSECOMPLETE.pdf As your issue with S&B is with style and consistency I think you could take brief look at each and decide whether they are more in line with you like to learn
